# In Civ 5, how do I move a unit out of a city?

Tags: civilization-5

So I moved my warrior into a city.  How do I get him out?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Click the unit icon (axe, spear, etc) above the city name.

Answer (score 1):

Switch into "Normal" 3D mode and then click on the unit icon above the city name.  I have this problem as well, but only when in "Strategic" flat mode.  If you still can not select the unit, it may be out of moves so you may have to wait a turn.